# Changing element's type on storyboard is possible?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

I put labels onto my storyboard, set up all constraints. Now, I have to use a UIView instead - is there a way to change the element's type from label to UIView? The interface builder doesn't seem to support it: do I have to remove the label, add the new view and set up again all the constraints?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the interface builder seems to not support it directly, I think you need to modify the Storyboard code yourself. Open it with the Source Code view (Right click -> Open As) and look for your labels, similar to this:

```
<label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="YWL-BD-gl8">
  <rect key="frame" x="20" y="300" width="42" height="21"/>
  <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
  <constraints>
      <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="42" id="jAd-Xg-3tc"/>
      <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="21" id="zeN-Ga-a3U"/>
  </constraints>
  <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
  <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
</label>
```

Then you can change the `<label` and `</label>` to `<view` and `</view>`, and it will become an UIView.

Probably  some attributes are not necessary any more (like the `<fontDescription>`), maybe you could add a UIView in the Interface Builder, see how it is coded in XML and see what properties are not necessary in order to remove them (just remember to not change the ID of the labels once changed to UIViews, since the constraints work using that ID).

Hope this helps!

Comment: That works only for the size constraints, distance ones (like vertical spacing) can't be copied that way.

Comment: @halakala True, I have edited the answer with another way that should work.

Comment: You're a legend! I should think to use the source editor more often!

Comment: Very helpful if you want to change an SCNView to a an ARSCNView without redoing all the constraints.  In the xml, an SCNView is called sceneKitView and ARSCNView is called arscnView -- a little inconsistent there.